# Magento product reviews not working at the front-end

Tags: product, review, ratings

Somehow I can't add reviews in the front-end of my Magento installation.

Initially I also wasn't able to add them in the back-end as well (404 error), but I resolved it with this tread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22846783/magento-admin-screens-add-new-review-button-not-working-and-generates-a-404-erro . So after this fix I can add them in the back-end and they show up in the front-end.

But now 1 problems remains. When I fill out the forms on the front-end and I hit 'Submit review' nothing happens. I hope someone can help me out.

Answer (score 2):

Replace your `form.phtml` with a same `form.phtml` file from `base/default/templates`. You can also get a copy from a fresh magento package.

Answer (score 2):

Go to system-configuration-advanced-system
CSRF protection Add secret key to url: select No

This solved for me the same problem.